# Get array from selected rows in controller with Datatables

Tags: jquery, post, datatables, symfony

I have a table displaying persons to select as members using Symfony 3 and Datatables. I can select one or multiple rows (members). Through Jquery I can get the id's of the selected members. Now I want to save the selected id's to my database as members. However I am struggling on how to get this done. 
My table newmembers.html.twig in twig has a submit button and looks like:

```
...

{% block body %}
{{ form_start(form) }}
<input type="submit" name="ids" id="submit" value="Add members" class="btn btn-primary" />

<table id="newmembers">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="hidden">Id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
        {% for person in persons %}
            <tr>
                <td class="hidden">{{ person.id }}</td>
                <td>{{ person.lastname }}, {{ person.initials }} {{ person.middlename }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
</table>
{{ form_end(form) }}
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#submit').click(function () {
                var ids = $.map(table.rows('.selected').data(), function (item) {
                    return item[0]
                });
                if (ids=='') {
                    alert('no member(s) selected');
                    return false;
                }
                return(ids);

    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

The variable ids now holds all member-id's I'd like to save.
In my controller I have come up with:

```
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    $members= new Member();
    $form = $this->createForm(MemberType::class, $member);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
       if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $members = $form->getData('ids'); 
        //check if I have any results//
        dump($members);die
        //add saving to database...//
       }

    return $this->render('member/newmember.html.twig', array(
        'persons' => $persons,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

The controller does not return any result for $members. Obviously I am missing something here: how to post the jquery array "ids" from my twig template to my controller.

What is the (best) way to post the jquery array of selected rows/id's to my controller as to save them to the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your ids in hidden input (inside your form). As this `<input type="hidden", name="ids", value="">`. You can set this value in jQuery submit event.

Comment: Thanks. I was just working on that and it seems to be the best solution.